# How do I push a play! framework java application to a Dokku in Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: java, git, playframework, digital-ocean

When I try to push a get an error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/webjars/WebJarExtractor$Cache : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

I realize the problem happens because when I execute the "push" action form Git, Dokku installs the OpenJdk 1.6, but I don't know how to solve this problem (I already installed the Oracle Jdk 8 on my digital ocean droplet). I am using the Ubuntu + Dokku image as well.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: Not yet, I am still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer:
if you are using Play-2.4.x (which requires JDK8) you should update dokku and buildsteps.

Example for just created dokku DO droplet.

Updating dokku:

```
cd ~/dokku
git pull --tags origin master
sudo DOKKU_BRANCH=master make install
```

Updating buildsteps:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/progrium/buildstep.git
cd buildstep
git pull origin master
sudo make build
```

Also you may not install JDK8 manually, it will be handled during deployment process.